# MVC5 AngularJS WebAPI Membership provider authentication on Azure

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, membership-provider

I am planning to build a MVC5 application on azure. This MVC application will be a web role. As per the requirement, this will not be a SPA (Single Page) and will be using Angular JS. Angular JS will talk to a Web API (running under a separate web role) to authenticate the users.
For authentication of users (to actually login to the system) we want to use the ASP.Net Membership provider. Database model will be EntityFramework with Code first.

So in short, user will enter the username and password in the frontend. The credentials will be passed to a web api through angularJS. Web Api will talk to a DAL (under worker role) and return if the user is authenticated or not.

Now as I am new to most of the stuff mentioned above, I really can't move ahead. Is there any pointers to a sample application, link implementing 
mvc5 <--> Web API <--> Membership provider

Comment: I find this series of articles to be quite good: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to following samples/videos

1. [Wintellect MVC Cookbook](https://github.com/Wintellect/Angular-MVC-Cookbook)
2. [Asp.Net Weblog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes)